# Make this effect in jquery (Apple Final Cut Features)

Tags: jquery, navigation, effect

Anyone have an idea how to recreate the effects seen on this page?

http://www.apple.com/finalcutpro/all-features/

As you can see, clicking an item on the left side of the screen causes the main content to scroll to the appropriate section, with no refresh.

In particular, look at the scrolling effect.

Answer (score 2):

1. There is a [plugin](http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/) for that. 2. you are looking at the answer. Investigate source of the link you gave.

Answer (score 0):

check "scrollTo()" and "animate" on jQuery.

a simple goolge search for "scroll to name jquery" or "scroll to div jquery" will give you plenty results and examples